# git bash: git@server: command not found

Tags: git, gitosis

I've got gitosis installed on my own private Ubuntu server.  It seems to be working great locally, however whenever I try to run a command from a different machine that talks to the server, I'm getting a "command not found" error.

For example, this works:

```
e:\src> git --version
git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0
```

However, this doesn't:

```
e:\SRC\www\listings>git clone git@server:listings
Cloning into listings...
bash: git@server: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Same result for any other command (push, pull, ls-remote, etc) that would talk to the server.

I'm relatively new to git, gitosis, and ubuntu (in case it didn't show :)) so I'm struggling to figure out how to even diagnose this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out.. GIT_SSH was set to use plink, however plink was (for some reason) using the defaults set via Putty.  So, doing **plink git@server** was logging in as my default user, not as git. Removing the user and server from the Default Settings in putty resolved the problem.

Awesome way to spend one's day.  >:(

Answer (score 3):

`git@server` defaults to the ssh protocol; do you have a git user setup on the remote machine, and have you setup ssh keys?

also, it should be

> listings.**git**

This will help you: http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html

Comment: Thanks the book helped a bit.. and the answer was yes to all the above questions.  :)